# Understanding a Theorem on Rotations as the Product of Reflections

Tags: geometry

I'm currently having trouble understanding this theorem, discussing reflections in a 2D plane:

> **Theorem:** If we perform a reflection $S_1$ about a line $l_1$ followed by a reflection $S_2$ about the line $l_2$, the resulting transformation is a rotation about the point of intersection Q of the two lines. The rotation is from the line $l_1$ to the line $l_2$, and by an angle $2 \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two lines.

Here's what I thought it meant, ***note that the angles of reflection are approximated,*** mostly due to never using GeoGebra before.

[image]

Anyways, it's looks somewhat clear that adding $\gamma+ \beta $ doesn't give either $\alpha$ nor $\delta$. Is there something I'm missing? If I made $\gamma= \beta$, would it then be the case that either $\gamma + \beta = \alpha$ or $\gamma+\beta = \delta$?

Comment: For the meaning of that statement see [the animation in an old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1839060/11619). The angle between the black and orange arrows is always twice the angle between the two lines.

Comment: That cleared up everything, thank you (:

Comment: Great! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure represents the situation of the theorem.

[image]

The point $E$ ir reflected at $E'$ than at $E''$. The transformation $E \to E''$ is a rotation around the point $F$ by an angle $ \angle EFE''$ tha is double the angle $\angle GFH$ between the two lines  because the triangles $EFE'$ and $E'FE''$ are isosceles.